# Is it acceptable in formal logic to achieve proof by contradiction by obtaining the negation of the assumption made?

Tags: logic

I am (re-)working through the Gensler logic book to refresh my command of formal logic. For the most part, he is using proof by contradiction to achieve results. I noticed that the proofs I am writing are somewhat different from his own. Typically, for a set of premises S and a conclusion Q, he assumes ~Q and then from there derives both A and ~A for some A, thereby proving Q. I realized that I have been assuming ~Q just as he has, but instead of finding a complementary A and ~A from there to make my contradiction, I have instead proved that Q is true from S and ~Q. Is this also contradictory, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's a contradiction too, just taking $A$ to be $Q$.

Comment: Very good to know! But see below.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine: you're proving $\neg Q\implies Q$, which implies $\neg Q\implies Q\wedge \neg Q$, so that $\neg Q$ again implies a contradiction.

Comment: HALLELUJAH! My question then is why no one else seems to draw attention to this in the logic texts that I've found.

Comment: Eh, I suppose just because it's a special case of the proof by contradiction they already cover. I'll comment that quite frequently people write proofs that start out by assuming $\neg Q$, prove $Q$ *without every using the assumption $\neg Q$*, and then conclude $Q$ "by contradiction!" So I'd have a look at your proofs to be sure the apparent contradiction you're deriving isn't really just disguising a direct proof.

Comment: I'm definitely not writing direct proofs here. I remember when I read Copi some time ago, but then forgot everything in there, he taught direct proofs. Gensler is all about indirect proofs and all the proofs I'm writing ultimately rely on the assumption of the negation of the thing to be prove that I'm making. I was sweating bullets for a moment because, if I had been mistaken, all my work would have been undone.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add some comments on this question from a formal point of view.

In mathematical logic, one way to formalize the *law of contradiction* is through the propositional law :

> $(A → B) → ((A → ¬B) → ¬A)$ --- **(*)**.

This form is [intuitionistically](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) valid; it is enough to change it a little bit, to have *classical* logic :

> $(\lnot A → B) → ((\lnot A → \lnot B) → A)$ --- **(§)**.

This law is easily derivable from **(*)** through *Double Negation* : $\lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$, which is not intuitionistically valid.

Having said that, the law we are discussing :

> > $(\lnot Q \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow Q$

is itself easily derivable from the *law of contradiction* :

*i)* $\lnot Q \rightarrow Q$ --- assumed

*ii)* $(\lnot Q → Q) → ((\lnot Q → \lnot Q) → Q)$ --- from **(§)** with $Q$ in place of both $A,B$ [this step amounts to applying Henning's comment above : "just taking $A$ to be $Q$"]

*iii)* $(\lnot Q → \lnot Q) → Q$ --- from i) and ii) by *modus ponens*

*iv)* $Q$ --- from iii) and the logic law : $A \rightarrow A$, by *modus ponens*

> *v)* $(\lnot Q \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow Q$ --- from i) and iv) by *Deduction Theorem*.

Thus, we are licensed to say that it is also a form of the *law of contradiction*.