# Questions on logic behind "proof by contradiction"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm trying to understand the logic behind "proof by contradiction" and hoping that I can clear up a few things in this post.

First of all, suppose I have a proposition $P$ and from this I can imply some statement $Q$, i.e.  $P\Rightarrow  Q$,  then to prove this by contradiction I assume the negation of this,  $\neg \left(P\Rightarrow  Q \right)$, which is equivalent to assuming $P\wedge \neg Q$, i.e.  $\neg \left(P\Rightarrow  Q \right)=P\wedge \neg Q$.  Is there any way to prove this algebraically (apologies,  I'm fairly new to logic)? I have shown this is true via a truth table,  but not sure whether this counts as a proof or not?!

Next,  having assumed $P\wedge \neg Q$,  following logically  from this if we find some statement $R$ such that a contradiction arises,  $R\wedge \neg R$ then it follows that $\neg \left(P\Rightarrow  Q \right)\Rightarrow R\wedge \neg R$.  Now, my understanding of this is that, as $R\wedge \neg R$ is always false, then the only way this implication can be true is if $\neg \left(P\Rightarrow  Q \right)$ is false,  which implies that $P\Rightarrow  Q $ is true,  hence proving think intial claim.  Is this the correct reasoning?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For the equivalence between $¬(P⇒Q)$ and $P∧¬Q$ we can prove it with a *proof system*, like *Natural Deduction*. Do you know it ?

Comment: Basically YES. See also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935727/is-it-acceptable-in-formal-logic-to-achieve-proof-by-contradiction-by-obtaining). In general, a proof by contradiction of $A$ exploit the following rule : $(¬A→B)→((¬A→¬B)→A)$. We assume the falsity of $A$, i.e. $\lnot A$ as true and derive both $B$ and $\lnot B$, i.e. a contradiction. Thus, by *modus ponens*, having proved $(¬A→B)$ and $(¬A→¬B)$ we can conclude with $A$. In your example, $A$ is $P⇒Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah, thanks for the information! I'm fairly new to the subject, so unfortunately haven't heard of 'Natural deduction'. If you know of any useful introductory notes on logic (and/or propositional logic) that you can suggest, that'd be great. In any case, really appreciate the help!

Comment: There are many good textbook. See e.g. Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Formal-Logic-Peter-Smith/dp/0521008042/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1411298221&sr=8-1&keywords=Peter+Smith+An+Introduction+to+Formal+Logic) (2003) and (available on-line) : Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @Will - Also, there is a way to prove the equivalence of $\neg (P \implies Q)$ and $P \wedge \neg Q$ algebraically. You can either consider the associate Boolean algebra or consider the implication sign as introducing a linear order among the truth values, i.e. $P \implies Q$ is true iff $[P] \leq [Q]$, where $[P]$ is the truth-value of $P$. On the other hand, take the $\wedge$ operation as the operation which gives you the inf of $[P]$ and $[Q]$ (this will give you a lattice, btw); it's not difficult to see that $[P] \leq [Q]$ iff $[P] \wedge [\neg Q] = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Naast :) ... Is proving it via a truth table (i.e. showing that the two logical connectives give equivalent truth tables) also valid/acceptable?

Comment: ^^ sorry, the above should have said "Nagase"  and not "Naast"...  Autocorrect fail!